# rails getting value from view to conroller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Having an issue getting a value from a form to the controller. I am using rails 4.0.

My view looks like this (new.html.erb)

```
<h1> POST A NEW LISTING </h>

    <% if current_user.nil? %>
        <h2>You must be logged in to view this page </h2>
    <% else %>
        <%= form_for [@user, @listing] do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :title, 'Title' %> <br />
      <%= f.text_field :title %>

      <%= f.label :general_info, 'General Information' %> <br />
      <%= f.text_area :general_info %>

      <%= f.label :included, 'Included' %> <br />
      <%= f.text_field :included %>

       <%= f.label :length, 'Length' %> <br />
      <%= f.text_field :length %>

      <%= f.label :price, 'Price' %> <br />
      <%= f.text_field :price %>

      <%= fields_for @tagging do |u| %>
        <%= u.label :tag, 'Tag' %> <br />
        <%= u.text_field :tag %>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.submit "submit" %>
    <% end %>

    <% end %>
```

I am trying to add tags. I have 2 models to handle the tags:

models -> tag.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :listings, through: :taggings
end
```

models -> tagging.rb

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :listing
end
```

tags keep track of the tag names themselves, while taggings keeps track of the connection to the listings.

When a user submits the form they will type in a string tag such as: "exampletag". I then need to search my tag model to get the tag_id of that specific tag. If it exists I need to put the tag_id and listing_id into taggings. Currently I have the listing_id correct, but I am having a problem even accessing the :tag symbol from the form.

This is what I have so far. Not that currently :tag_id is hardcoded in because I cant get @current_tag to return the information I need.

listings_conroller.rb #create

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @listing = @user.listings.build(listing_params)     
    #save before we get the listing ID

    if @listing.save

        @current_tag = Tag.where(:name => params[:tag])
          @taggings = Tagging.new(:tag_id => 1, :listing_id => @listing.id)

        if @taggings.save
            flash[:success] = "Success"
            redirect_to root_path 
        else
          render :action => 'new'
        end
    else
     render :action => 'new'
    end

  end
```

I thought that @current_tag = Tag.where(:name => params[:tag]) would return the correct listing but it seems to be returning null when I submit the form with a name which is in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it!

Since tags is nested under taggings I needed to access the param as:

```
params[:tagging][:tag]
```

instead of params[:tag]